# loading data on scroll down not working in IE due to smooth scrolling

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, smooth-scrolling

I am building an ecommerce website.
i am getting data(products to display) from database and storing it it cache and fetching data from cache on scroll down event. this works perfectly in all browsers even IE but only if smooth scrolling is turned off.  why is this is happening?
It works if smooth scrolling is disabled.
 is there any way to disable smooth scrolling programatically. im using asp.net.?

if smooth scrolling is enabled the entire cache data is displayed in one shot rather than loading the data little by little. the data is displayed again and again on each scroll down.

im new to programming. so kindly forgive the mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only answer i found is,
Mr. sujit,

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
  $('body').on("mousewheel", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var wd = event.wheelDelta;
    var csp = window.pageYOffset;
    //alert(wd+','+csp);
    window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
  });
```

use this function in u r scroll condition.